# Swift: How do I update property when state property changes?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a collection of audio files.

I am displaying a collection of cover images for each episode using [ACarousel](https://github.com/JWAutumn/ACarousel) that takes an index `$currIndex`.

I have a `player` object. It stores the current episode (`player.currentEpisode = episode`).

I can reference a particular episode from outside the carousel loop like so: `player.episodes[currIndex]`.

I want to change `player.currentEpisode` every time `currIndex` updates: `player.currentEpisode = player.episodes[currIndex]`. I thought I could do this using `didSet` or `willSet` but it appears these aren't fired.

Why don't `didSet` or `willSet` fire? How can I update `player.currentEpisode` when `currIndex` updates?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var player: Player
    
    ...
    
    @State var currIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("Did set currIndex") // Nothing output to console
        }

        willSet {
            print("Will set currIndex") // Nothing output to console
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ACarousel(player.episodes, id: \.id, index: $currIndex, spacing: width/5, sidesScaling: 0.7, isWrap: true) { episode in
                    VStack {
                        Image(episode.image)
                    }
            }

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use instead `onChange(of: )`, like

```
@State var currIndex: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        ACarousel(player.episodes, id: \.id, index: $currIndex, spacing: width/5, sidesScaling: 0.7, isWrap: true) { episode in
                VStack {
                    Image(episode.image)
                }
        }
        .onChange(of: currIndex) { [currIndex] newValue in // << here !!
           print("Old value: \(currIndex)")
           print("New value: \(newValue)")
        }
```